# Puppeteer get url of webpage opened in new tab

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm writing a web scraper to verify dates of sports events. One website is not showing sport event url on the listing, but instead link
like: [www.domain.com/redirectsystem/id12345](http://www.domain.com/redirectsystem/id12345) etc, once clicked new tab is being opened with the event website. What I want to achieve is to get url of this website opened in new tab.

I have managed to click the link with puppeteer, website is being opened in new tab but I don't know how to get the url information

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   headless: false,
   'args' : [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
        ]
  });

  const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page())));
      await page.click('span.link-hightlight');

      const newPage = await newPagePromise; 
      const url = await newPage.url() // this is not working 
      console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `page.evaluate` to retrieve any information from web page context:

```
const url = await newPage.evaluate(() => document.location.href);
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 14):

You can simply use `page.url()` to get the page URL

```
const url = await page.url();
console.log(url);
```